# Find average event counts

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of events, so `db.events` contains many:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e56c7d0c0c979b198cbe21a"),
    "event" : "buy",
    "userId" : "u1",
    "itemId" : "iPhone 12",
}
```

The collection is large and contains several types of events so I need to use the aggregation framework. I need to calculate:

- the average unique`itemId`'s a unique `userId` `buy`'s.

To be clear my question is how to take an average of the resulting counts. I need a collection of essentially `userId: [itemId1, itemId2, ...]` containing every `userId` from `buy` events and `itemId`'s grouped by the `usereId`. I want to average the count of unique `itemId`'s over all `userId`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      event: "buy"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      set: {
        $addToSet: "$itemId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      unique: {
        $sum: {
          $size: "$set"
        }
      },
      n: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      avg: {
        $divide: [
          "$unique",
          "$n"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Er1HqcOH8s2)

Comment: The question is how to average over many collection counts. I removed the 2 cases in the example above to be more clear.

Comment: @pferrel I've updated my answer. We can get your second case (if you wish) with `$facet`

Comment: @pferrel How about [this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZF91981HWJa)?

Comment: @pferrel Check it, I got what you need :D

Comment: That gives the wrong answer. Looking at the data you can see that there are on average 2 itemIds bought per user since they both have 2. But the answer of the query comes out 1???

Comment: I was playing around with it and added another itemId for u1, so u1 bought 3 unique items and u2 bought 2 unique items. But the answer here is 1.6666??? It should be (2+3)/2 = 2.5. https://mongoplayground.net/p/HxmeYlEZF8j

Comment: @pferrel You have the wrong link, click the link posted in my answer, it gives 2.5

Comment: Aha, yes, that's a great help. Now I will try to follow what you did and learn something. Many thanks